# vimdiff foldmethod in two files

Tags: vim, vi

I am comparing two files with vimdiff. I am trying to fold some parts of
the files simultaneously. I type

set foldmethod=manual

in one of the files but it folds the text in that file only when I type 'zf'.

Is it possible (with some autocmd function) to fold simultaneously text in
two files in vimdiff?

Another thing is that I want to update the diff (with diffupdate) automatically
whenever I write the file instead of having to type 'diffupdate'. Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't ask two mostly unrelated questions in the same post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how manual folding would be synced across buffers in vim considering the text may be different in the two buffers.  Text you are selecting in one buffer might not match the text in the second buffer.  I haven't used manual folding in a very long time so I'm not that familiar with it.  Take this with a grain of salt.

As for your second question, you can run `diffupdate` when saving files by using the following autocmd.  I've wrapped this in a test so that it only runs if vim was launched in diff mode.  If you use diff mode from within a running vim I don't think it will work correctly.

```
if &diff
  augroup saveupdatediff
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost * diffupdate
  augroup END
endif
```